# How to do CRUD operations on multiple tables at the same time

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I am using SQL Server (T-SQL) and I have two tables to hold record values, that were previously been one.

**RecordValueSmall**:

```
id INT, recordId INT, value NVARCHAR(100)
```

**RecordValueLarge**:

```
id INT, recordId INT, value NVARCHAR(1000)
```

**Record**:

```
id INT, type INT
```

I would like to modify stored procedures that read and insert into appropriate table based on record type.

I have tried creating view, but problem is inserting into it.

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[RecordView]
AS
SELECT id, recordId, value
FROM   dbo.RecordValueSmall
UNION
SELECT id, recordId, value
FROM   dbo.RecordValueLarge
```

Is there some way to work with both tables at the same time, without adding too much logic into existing procedures?

Comment: The first big question is, **why**? That sounds like a really bad design... and the only way to handle inserts is with conditional logic.

Comment: @DaleK It is mostly for performance reasons, because those tables are really big with a lot of entries

Comment: That doesn't sound like a good way to solve performance issues. Splitting records into those with a small `nvarchar` column and those with a large doesn't not sound right. I would really be sure thats the correct decision before making these kinds of architectural changes. As you can already see its adding to the complexity.

Comment: `nvarchar(1000)` with a small string in it is stored quite small in the database. The only issue can be the estimated data size. Be that as it may, perhaps a [Partitioned View](https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-server-partitioned-views/) might be a solution, barring that `instead of` triggers

Comment: I would agree with @DaleK - I'd be very surprised to see execution plans indicating that this method has better performance than the single table .....  But Dale is also correct about the conditional logic - and you say that you're using a stored proc to do inserts (and presumably updates), so you'll have the ability to apply logic to the incoming data and insert/update/delete accordingly.  A view combining these two tables is not going to be your solution

Comment: @DaleK , thank you for your comment. There is one more reason for splitting it like this, in the future I will have to add new value types, like Date and INT, instead of text

Comment: @Mirhat still sounds like the wrong design. Its sounds like you are attempting to build some form of generic storage system, which is a total anti-pattern in SQL Server. I would be revisiting your design before implementing what you are suggesting.

Comment: Thank you all for suggestions, I will look into Partitioned Views

Comment: @Mirhat You will be able to do this with a stored proc.

Comment: I really don't think a Partitioned View will work, in this instance.  You're going to apply constraints on the tables how, exactly, to support the Partitioned View?  Length of the value, whether it's numeric or date?  I don't really think that will even work.  Plus, for the Partitioned View to work properly, I believe that the column/s that are involved in the partitioning must be part of each table's primary key - if you're concerned about large tables, then you likely wouldn't want to have your value columns as part of the primary key.  So then you're back to reviewing the design again ....

Comment: I don't understand what problem you are trying to solve.  Why not just create an updatable view on the `records` table and use a trigger to determine which of the other tables should be updated?